# Play video on canvas and preserve the last frame/image on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I'm using the following script code to draw a video on canvas:

```
$("#vPlayer").on('play', function (e) {
           var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           var $this = this;
           canvas.width = 640;
           canvas.height = 480;
           (function loop() {
               if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
                   ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                   setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
               }
           })();

});
```

The code works well, but in my case, I want to change the video source (src attribute) of the video tag every 2 mins. When I set the src attr for the video and during the loading time for the video, the canvas displays white screen. How can I preserve the last image of video and do not clear the canvas?

It is a little bit weird because, when I don't set the width and height for the canvas, the last frame is preserved, but I need to set the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you set the size of the canvas it will be cleared.

To avoid this you need to set the size at the "beginning", before you start drawing to it. In this case I would recommend you set it outside your event handler as well as the initializing of the canvas and context variable:

```
var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;

$("#vPlayer").on('play', function (e) {
   var $this = this;
   (function loop() {
       if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
           ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0, 640, 480);
           setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
       }
   })();
});
```

Comment: OMG, many thanks @ken-fyrstenberg :) I really appreciate your quick answer, you saved my day :)