# How to refresh Canvas/context with a new video frame image every 5 sec. in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

how to refresh Canvas/context with a new video frame image every 5 sec. in HTML5 from within the script ?

Canas/context can be still refreshed with Snap Photo button event (human action)

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Comment: question is self-explanatory if you know the answer

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague, but you can play the video and use a `setTimeout`in which you can draw the current video frame to the canvas with `drawImage`.

Comment: whatever that's supposed to mean

Comment: setTimeout exactly replaces Snap Photo button click event in a single run. If I stick the same script twice, I don't get image refresh. Fred advised me to insert demo code, exactly I did in my another question, receiving no reply. I am afraid canvas/context is run in protected mode, once populated with image (array) rejects overwrite with a new image if run from within the script and Snap Photo button click event gets higher priority disabling overwrite protection set. If I am wrong please correct me. Just test context.clear

Comment: There is alike question already answered    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249529/play-video-on-canvas-and-preserve-the-last-frame-image-on-canvas?rq=1                                                              var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;

$("#vPlayer").on('play', function (e) {
   var $this = this;
   (function loop() {
       if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
           ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0, 640, 480);
           setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
       }
   })();
});

Comment: Just another nice snapshot from video example, no loop support for image refresh  http://appcropolis.com/blog/web-technology/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video//

Comment: Great idea eureka!!!  from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249529/play-video-on-canvas-and-preserve-the-last-frame-image-on-canvas?rq=1   >>>>>>>>>                                                                "Every time you set the size of the canvas it will be cleared."  So I need to clear the canvas by looping "set the size of the canvas"